# Create a new layer every time I make anything new in Illustrator as in photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, illustrator-effects

As we add a new shape or insert an image in photoshop there is a new layer created every time but this is not happening in Illustrator.
The whole project of mine is created in 1 layer only but I don't want that.
I want each layer to get separated .
Hope you get my query

Answer (score 4):

Layers are inherently different in Photoshop and Illustrator. Everything in Photoshop is a layer, but Illustrator's Layers panel is actually layers and objects. Everything is created on one layer by default but you can still open that layer and see each object as it's own "layer".

If you do want everything on it's own layer (although you probably don't need to), you can do so by selecting the top level layer in the Layers panel and choosing "Release to Layers (Sequence)" from the panel menu:

[image: Illustrator release layers]

[image: Illustrator released layers]

Comment: What does it matter if its one leyer up or down? Also worth noting illustrator makes much more objects than photoshop. I mean 100 layers in PS is problematic a 1000 even more so. 1000 in illustrator is a normal day in the office

Answer (score -3):

In photoshop the command Ctrl+Shift+N does the trick for me. Just do this every time before you work on a new item.

Comment: As the question is about Illustrator, I fail to see how this answers the question? Please explain!